# Laravel Redirect to previous dynamic page after login

Tags: laravel

I wonder how I can redirect a user after login?

Lets say that I am on the page "www.mysite.com/users/2"
Then I try to edit a blog post without being logged in and get sent to the login page, efter login I wish to return to "www.mysite.com/users/2"

I have tried this so far:

```
if (Auth::attempt($credentials,$remember)) {
            return redirect()->back();
        } else {
          return redirect()->back()->withErrors([trans('api.couldnotlogin')]);
        }
```

But `return redirect()->back();` will only redirect me to "www.mysite.com/"

**Update**

I got it working using this:

```
public function showLoginForm()
    {
      $previous_url = Session::get('_previous.url');
        $ref = isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']) ? $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] : '';
        $ref = rtrim($ref, '/');
        if ($previous_url != url('login')) {
            Session::put('referrer', $ref);
            if ($previous_url == $ref) {
                Session::put('url.intended', $ref);
            }
        }
      return view('auth.login');
    }

    public function loginUser(ApiAuthUserPassRequest $request)
    {
      if ($request->has('rememberme')) {
          $remember = $request->input('rememberme');
      } else {
        $remember = false;
      }
        $credentials = ['email' => $request->input('email'), 'password' => $request->input('password')];
        if (Auth::attempt($credentials,$remember)) {
            if (Session::has('referrer')) {
              return redirect()->intended(Session::pull('referrer'));
            } else {
              return redirect('/account');
            }
        } else {
          return redirect()->back()->withErrors([trans('api.couldnotlogin')]);
        }

    }
```

Comment: why don't you use the laravel default login?

Comment: @jycr753 I made my own login since I accept different type of users, anyhow I got it working now. See my updated question

Comment: @user2722667 try this `return Redirect::intended();`

Comment: That is actually a good solution... cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

Laravel 5.1 have trait `Illuminate/Foundation/Validation/ValidatesRequests.php` with method

```
protected function getRedirectUrl()
{
    return app(UrlGenerator::class)->previous();
}
```

where `UrlGenerator` is `Illuminate/Routing/UrlGenerator.php`. You can try use `previous()` method.

Comment: I tried that but I just got redirected to "/" I am using L5.4 if that matters, anyhow I got it working now, see my updated question